# Null or 0 values in dijit.form.datetextbox

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, dijit.form

I'm using a standard output of Zend_Dojo_Element_DateTextbox AKA dijit.form.datetextbox... I want to use NULL or 0 values, but it always defaults to 11/30/1899... is there a simple option to enable this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTextBox accepts a NULL or empty string... it just screws up when you insert a 0 (zero).